# Trying to change a portion of my URL when going to profile page

Tags: php

Short and simple, trying to have a URL like facebook has. [www.facebook.com/username](http://www.facebook.com/username) . Where do I start? I want to get the username portion when I go to a profile.

Comment: Start by researching the keywords _URL rewriting_ and _front controller pattern_.

Comment: This depends on the webserver you are using, since it handles mapping the path in the URL to files - or to anything else that it's configured to.

Comment: what doesit mean , `I want to get the username portion when I go to a profile.` ?

Comment: you can't by just using pure php, you need to learn .htaccess to  rewrite the url. in your case, try to view profile first this way www.facebook.com/profile.php?username=YourUserName. If you are using framework like codeigniter, laravel or etc this is very easy.

Comment: @KUMAR basically hen you go to facebook, click profile, it goes to the user profile. In the URL it shows facebook.com/username. I am trying to get the username portion of the website rather than it showing "profile.php"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code I think this code will solve your issue.**

```
<?php
    
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')
        $link = "https";
    else
        $link = "http";
    
    // Here append the common URL characters.
    $link .= "://";
    
    // Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL.
    $link .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    
    // Append the requested resource location to the URL
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        
    // string start index
    $start = strlen($link) - strlen($uri);
    
    $requiredName = substr($link, $start + 1);

    echo $requiredName;

?>
```

Comment: I am kind of new to PHP and I would assume I jumped into a tough project for a beginner but can you tell me if I am thinking correctly? Basically when you go to facebook and go to a profile, the URL is www.facebook.com/username. The original URL would be "www.facebook.com/profile?username" and is rewritten to basically hide the "profile?" ? Is that correct?

Comment: if any thing in url attributes(after ?) then you get username like as $username = $_GET['username '];
its a one line solution

Comment: But what I am trying to figure out is instead of the page URL saying www.facebook.com/profile.php?username , I would like for it to just say www.facebook.com/username when I go to a profile page.

Comment: shared code is a solution of that query, I will work for any kind link like this (www.facebook.com/username)